# How can I upgrade PostgreSQL from version 11 to version 13?

Tags: postgresql, debian

I'm trying to upgrade PostgreSQL from 11 to 13 on a Debian system, but it fails. I have a single cluster that needs to be upgraded:

```
$ sudo -u postgres pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
11  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/11/main  /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log
```

Here's what I've tried to upgrade it:

```
$ sudo -u postgres pg_upgradecluster 11 main
Stopping old cluster...
Warning: stopping the cluster using pg_ctlcluster will mark the systemd unit as failed. Consider using systemctl:
  sudo systemctl stop postgresql@11-main
Restarting old cluster with restricted connections...
Notice: extra pg_ctl/postgres options given, bypassing systemctl for start operation
Error: cluster configuration already exists
Error: Could not create target cluster
```

After this, the system is left in an unusable state:

```
$ sudo systemctl status postgresql@11-main.service 
● postgresql@11-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-06-14 06:48:20 CEST; 19s ago
    Process: 597 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 11-main start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE>
    Process: 4508 ExecStop=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect -m fast 11-main stop (code=exited, status=>
   Main PID: 684 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1.862s

Jun 14 06:47:23 argos systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main...
Jun 14 06:47:27 argos systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main.
Jun 14 06:48:20 argos postgresql@11-main[4508]: Cluster is not running.
Jun 14 06:48:20 argos systemd[1]: postgresql@11-main.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARG>
Jun 14 06:48:20 argos systemd[1]: postgresql@11-main.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 14 06:48:20 argos systemd[1]: postgresql@11-main.service: Consumed 1.862s CPU time.

$ sudo systemctl start postgresql@11-main.service 
Job for postgresql@11-main.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status postgresql@11-main.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Luckily, rebooting the system brought the old cluster back online, but nothing has been upgraded. Why does the upgrade fail? What are "the steps required by its unit configuration"? How can I upgrade PostgreSQL with minimal downtime?

Comment: See [this](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/upgrading-postgresql-11-postgresql-13-timescaledb-and-postgis-linux-using-pgupgrade)

Comment: That does not explain the error I got

Comment: what does `pg_lsclusters` tell? Did you install `timesacleDB` and change the config file accordingly?

Comment: I've added the output of `pg_lsclusters`. I am not using `timescaleDB`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found the source of my problem: a configuration file owned by the wrong user (`root` instead of `postgres`) that could not be removed by the `pg_dropcluster` command because I ran it as the user `postgres`.

For future reference, here are the correct steps to upgrade a PostgreSQL cluster from 11 to 13:

- Verify the current cluster is the still the old version:

  ```
  $ pg_lsclusters
  Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
  11  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/11/main  /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log
  13  main    5434 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/13/main  /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-13-main.log
  ```
- Run `pg_dropcluster 13 main` as user `postgres`:

  ```
  $ sudo -u postgres pg_dropcluster 13 main
  Warning: systemd was not informed about the removed cluster yet. 
  Operations like "service postgresql start" might fail. To fix, run:
  sudo systemctl daemon-reload
  ```
- Run the `pg_upgradecluster` command as user `postgres`:

  ```
  $ sudo -u postgres pg_upgradecluster 11 main
  ```
- Verify that everything works, and that the only online cluster is now 13:

  ```
  $ pg_lsclusters 
  Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
  11  main    5434 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/11/main  /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log
  13  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/13/main  /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-13-main.log
  ```
- Drop the old cluster:

  ```
  $ sudo -u postgres pg_dropcluster 11 main
  ```
- Uninstall the previous version of PostgreSQL:

  ```
  $ sudo apt remove 'postgresql*11'
  ```

Answer (score 2):

The Debian packages create a cluster automatically when you install the server package, so get rid of that:

```bash
pg_dropcluster 13 main
```

Then stop the v11 server and try again.

Comment: I've done this, as shown by the output of `pg_lsclusters`. There is no v13 cluster, only a v11 cluster, and the `pg_upgradecluster` command still fails.

Comment: Your question showed the `pg_lscluster` output *before* you installed the software. It is hard to figure out what exactly happened with such inaccuracies...

Comment: Let me try to be accurate: I had already dropped the empty cluster before I started to write this question. Then, I reproduced the error multiple times by running `pg_upgradecluster` and capturing the output I needed. It fails every time with the same error, so the problem is not that a cluster 13 already exists.